# How to know programmatically which is the last object that has the animation

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations

Is there a way for me to know programmatically on which object the CSS animation applies last

For example,

```css
.r1 {
     animation-name: move1;
     animation-delay: 2.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 .c1 {
     animation-name: blink;
     animation-delay: 0.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 2;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 /*.text1 {
     animation-name: scl;
     animation-delay: 5.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 2;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}*/
 .r2 {
     transform-origin: center;
     transform-box: fill-box;
     animation-name: gr;
     animation-delay: 3.5s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 .r3 {
     animation-name: move2;
     animation-delay: 7.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 @keyframes move1 {
     to {
         transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
 @keyframes blink {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
    }
}
 @keyframes gr {
     from {
         transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
     to {
         transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes scl {
     to {
         transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}  
 @keyframes move2 {
     to {
         transform: translateY(400px);
    }
}  
        }
```

```html
  <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <rect id="r1" class="r1" x="10" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
  <rect id="r2" class="r2" x="10" y="130" width="100" height="100" fill="green" />
  <rect id="r3" class="r3" x="10" y="240" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />

  <circle id="c1" class="c1" cx="50" cy="400" r="40" fill="orange" />
  <text class="text1" id="text1" x="80" y="500" font-size="30" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
</svg>
```

In this, I have 5 elements and I am applying animation on 4 of them and `r3` is the last element on which the animation applies. Is there a way I can detect the `animation-delay+animation-duration` for `r3`- the last element on which the animation applies with javascript.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are after: get notified when the last animation finishes and identify which one it was, or identify, independently of the animation actually running, which will finish last, or get the time when the animation on `.r3` will finish (because you know in advance that it will be last)?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you mean by 'detect'. Is this is just some code in JS that looks up animation-delay and animation-duration settings, which can be done, or is it to somehow measure the time between the page loading and the ending of the animation on r3, which can't be done (well, not totally accurately as we aren't in a real time systems environment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) can inspect animations.

`document.getAnimations()` returns all animations found in the document. Each of them has an `effect` property, and in your case, they are all of the type `KeyframeEffect`.

- `animation.animationName` returns the animation name as stated in the CSS `@keyframes` declaration.
- `animation.effect.target` returns the element targeted by the animation.
- `animation.effect.getComputedTiming().endTime` returns the time the animation ends.

From there you can compare and filter the information you need.

```js
document.getAnimations().forEach(animation => {
    console.log(
        animation.animationName,
        animation.effect.target.id,
        animation.effect.getComputedTiming().endTime
    );
});
```

```css
.r1 {
     animation-name: move1;
     animation-delay: 2.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 .c1 {
     animation-name: blink;
     animation-delay: 0.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 2;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 /*.text1 {
     animation-name: scl;
     animation-delay: 5.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 2;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}*/
 .r2 {
     transform-origin: center;
     transform-box: fill-box;
     animation-name: gr;
     animation-delay: 3.5s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 .r3 {
     animation-name: move2;
     animation-delay: 7.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 @keyframes move1 {
     to {
         transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
 @keyframes blink {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
    }
}
 @keyframes gr {
     from {
         transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
     to {
         transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes scl {
     to {
         transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}  
 @keyframes move2 {
     to {
         transform: translateY(400px);
    }
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <rect id="r1" class="r1" x="10" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
  <rect id="r2" class="r2" x="10" y="130" width="100" height="100" fill="green" />
  <rect id="r3" class="r3" x="10" y="240" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />

  <circle id="c1" class="c1" cx="50" cy="400" r="40" fill="orange" />
  <text class="text1" id="text1" x="80" y="500" font-size="30" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow !!! many thanks for this. I was looking for this.

Comment: @ccprog: thank you so much  for this excellent example! Regarding the buggy console.log output: it's actually showing up ... but pretty delayed. This odd behavior seems be related to the 'complete' node output called by `animation.effect.target` while it's still animating.  Changing this line to `animation.effect.target.id` would circumvent this issue.

Comment: @herrstrietzel: Oh yeah. that is one I could have thought of myself...(well, not). Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @ccprog: My pleasure! Actually I think it's a pity these rather new (... still in ie battle mode) natively supported API capabilities/improvements slightly tend to "fall off the radar" in general perception compared the next ultimate framework (introducing a plethora of dependetn modules).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this using [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) like so :-

```js
const animatedElements = [];
const noOfElementsToAnimate = 4;
const svgLayer = document.querySelector('#Layer_1');

const onAnimationEnd = (e) => {
  animatedElements.push(e.target.id);
  if (animatedElements.length === noOfElementsToAnimate) {
    svgLayer.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
    console.log(animatedElements[animatedElements.length - 1])
  }
}

svgLayer.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
```

```css
.r1 {
  animation-name: move1;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.c1 {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


/*.text1 {
     animation-name: scl;
     animation-delay: 5.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 2;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}*/

.r2 {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation-name: gr;
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.r3 {
  animation-name: move2;
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes move1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes gr {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes scl {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes move2 {
  to {
    transform: translateY(400px);
  }
}


}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <rect id="r1" class="r1" x="10" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
  <rect id="r2" class="r2" x="10" y="130" width="100" height="100" fill="green" />
  <rect id="r3" class="r3" x="10" y="240" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />

  <circle id="c1" class="c1" cx="50" cy="400" r="40" fill="orange" />
  <text class="text1" id="text1" x="80" y="500" font-size="30" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
</svg>
```

**Explanation:** - Here I attached the event listener for `animationend` event to the parent element i.e. **Layer_1 svg**.
Whenever the animation will end for its children elements, I push the `id` of that element to an array and compare it with an existing no which denote the no of animated elements that are in the DOM (can use a unique class to fetch these dynamically as well). When the `animatedElements` and `noOfElementsToAnimate`  are equal, I remove the listener and log/use the last value of `animatedElements` array.

Alternatively, you can also ditch the array and just use one variable to keep track of last animated element, say, `lastAnimatedElement` and decrement `noOfElementsToAnimate` and log the `lastAnimatedElement` when `noOfElementsToAnimate` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this which calculates the `Delay+(Duration*Iteration-Count)` for each of the svg elements and at the end returns the max value of that expression, which would be the total duration of the last element on which the animation ran. The last element with the animation logically will have the longest `Delay+(Duration*Iteration-Count)` which I need to pass on as an `animation-delay` for my next element for animation.

```js
var _layer1 = document.querySelectorAll('svg > *');
var _max = -1;
for (const el of _layer1) {
    var __del = getComputedStyle(el).animationDelay;
    var __del = __del.split(',');
    var __delLast = parseFloat(__del[__del.length - 1]);
    var __duration = getComputedStyle(el).animationDuration;
    var __duration = __duration.split(',');
    var __durationLast = parseFloat(__duration[__del.length - 1]);
    var __iterationCount = getComputedStyle(el).animationIterationCount;
    var __iterationCount = __iterationCount.split(',');
    var __iterationCountLast = parseFloat(__iterationCount[__iterationCount.length - 1]);

    function alternate(a, b) {
        if (isNaN(a)) {
            return b
        } else {
            return a
        }
    };
    var modified = alternate(__iterationCountLast, __durationLast);
    var _expression = __delLast + (__durationLast * modified); //Delay+(Duration*Iteration-Count)
    _max = Math.max(_max, _expression);
};
```

```css
.r1 {
     animation-name: move1;
     animation-delay: 2.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 .c1 {
     animation-name: blink;
     animation-delay: 0.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 2;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 /*.text1 {
     animation-name: scl;
     animation-delay: 5.5s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: 2;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}*/
 .r2 {
     transform-origin: center;
     transform-box: fill-box;
     animation-name: gr;
     animation-delay: 3.5s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 .r3 {
     animation-name: move2;
     animation-delay: 7.5s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 @keyframes move1 {
     to {
         transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
 @keyframes blink {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
    }
}
 @keyframes gr {
     from {
         transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
     to {
         transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes scl {
     to {
         transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}  
 @keyframes move2 {
     to {
         transform: translateY(400px);
    }
}  
        }
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
</svg>
```